# wp_set_script_translations does not load the translation file

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, language-translation

i am following the [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/internationalization/) about translating a custom block. this is my languages folder [image] and then in the plugin init function i try to load it. this is my code [image] but when i insert my custom block it is not translated, so wordpress doesn't load the translation.
what am i missing?
best regards

additional information:

this is the block-plugin init function, maybe i do something wrong there?

```
function create_block_gutrs_slider_block_init() {

//register scripts
/**
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/#enqueuing-block-scripts
 */
// automatically load dependencies and version
$asset_file = include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php');

wp_register_script(
    'gutrs-slider-front-script',
    plugins_url( 'build/gutrsfrontscript.js', __FILE__ ),
    ['wp-i18n'],
    $asset_file['version']
);

/**
 * translation
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/internationalization/
 */

if (function_exists('wp_set_script_translations')) {
    wp_set_script_translations( 'gutrs-slider-script', 'gutrs-slider', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' );
}

register_block_type( __DIR__ ,array(
    'script' => 'gutrs-slider-front-script'
));
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_gutrs_slider_block_init' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the function **wp_set_script_translations** you need to **register** or **load** your script with **wp-i18n** dependency:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts()
{
  wp_enqueue_script( 'gutrs-slider-script', **YOUR_SCRIPT_URL**, ['wp-i18n'] );
  wp_set_script_translations( 'gutrs-slider-script', 'gutrs-slider', **LANGUAGES PATH**);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

**wp_set_script_translations** need is inside of **wp_enqueue_scripts** action

Comment: hi, it still doesn't use the translation. thank you for answering. i have added my full init function.